# Doing quotes in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some legacy CSS I wanted to clean up. Person who wrote it is not available for consultation. The following rule does not validate (CSS 2.1):

```
html[lang=en] q: before, : lang(en) q: before {
    content: "“";
}
```

Would it be safe to assume that the author mean the following (this validates):

```
html[lang=en] q:before, q:lang(en):before {
    content: "“";
}
```

Also, is the first selector different from the second one in any way? Is each specific to a certain browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector does not appear to work in Firefox:

```
: lang(en) q: before
```

It is probably supposed to be

```
:lang(en) q:before
```

Which is not the same as

```
q:lang(en):before
```

You can see this in action with the following test case:

```
:lang(en) q:before {
  content: "a";
}
q:lang(en):before {
  content: "b";
}

<div lang="en">
<q lang="zh">Hello zh</q> <q lang="en">Hello EN</q> <q>Hello Plain</q>
</div>
```

This gives

```
 a"Hello zh" b"Hello EN" b"Hello Plain"
```

Basically the `:lang(en) q:before` rule says "Before any Q inside any element with English language", while `q:lang(en):before` says "before any Q that is in the English Language".

Also, the two selectors that are used (`html[lang=en] q:before` and `:lang(en) q:before`) are not exactly equivalent but will achieve the same effect most of the time if the browser in question understands one of the selectors.  :lang(en) is a newer selector that identifies the language while html[lang=en] is an attribute selector that merely identifes some attribute called `lang`.

Answer (score 0):

this is definately wrong :

```
before, : lang(en)
```

the `, :` can't be used like this, the comma indicates a new "rule", the colon a pseudp property (like in `a:link`).

P.S. do `content` and `before` work in IE?

Comment: Excellent question! They don't. I'm not even sure why that rule was included, as the <q> tag is currently not being used anywhere on the site. Probably in case of some future use.